# How to get file information?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have an existing file on the computer and I was wondering if it is possible to know when it was made, Size of the file, and more properties on the file..

I tried to use in ifstream But there's the information I have on file

(I'm using Visual C++ 6.0,Cannot using Boost)

Comment: Seriously VC6? As in fifteen years old? You probably want either [stat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) to use a POSIX-like API or [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364946.aspx) from the Windows API.

Comment: MFC (which you have tagged this question with) offers up [`CFileFind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h3beets(v=vs.80).aspx), which should give you what you seek.

Comment: WhozCraig,How can I open with CFileFind that my file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at function [`GetFileAttributesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
#include <windows.h>

WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fInfo;

GetFileAttributesEx("test.dat", GetFileExInfoStandard, &fInfo);
```

The [`WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains a lot of the "common" file informations (size, creation/edit time, attributes).

**Update:** I just saw, that you're using Visual C++ 6. Since `GetFileAttributesEx` is supported since Windows XP it might not be available in your WIN API headers... You can use the function by dynamic linking. The following code does the same thing as the snippet from above:

```
/* clone definition of WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA from WINAPI header */
typedef struct file_info_struct
{
    DWORD    dwFileAttributes;
    FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    DWORD    nFileSizeHigh;
    DWORD    nFileSizeLow;
} FILE_INFO;

/* function pointer to GetFileAttributesEx */
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *GET_FILE_ATTRIBUTES_EX)(LPCWSTR lpFileName, int fInfoLevelId, LPVOID lpFileInformation);


HMODULE hLib;
GET_FILE_ATTRIBUTES_EX func;
FILE_INFO fInfo;

hLib = LoadLibrary("Kernel32.dll");
if (hLib != NULL)
{
    func = (GET_FILE_ATTRIBUTES_EX)GetProcAddress(hLib, "GetFileAttributesExW");
    if (func != NULL)
    {
        func("test.dat", 0, &fInfo);
    }

    FreeLibrary(hLib);

    /*
    ** Don't call func after FreeLibrary !!!
    ** It should be ok since kernel32.dll is loaded by your application anyway but if
    ** you get a function pointer from a dll only loaded by LoadLibrary the function
    ** pointer is invalid once the library if freed.
    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
How can I view the creation date of a file? fInfo.ftCreationTime is FILETIME (is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1) so How can I view a date? (dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: @MikeBrown Have a look at function `FileTimeToSystemTime`.

Comment: You are mixing character encodings. If you use `LPCTSTR` in your function prototype declaration, you cannot use `"GetFileAttributesExA"` to look up the function pointer. Either use `LPCSTR` in your declaration (with `"GetFileAttributesExA"`), or use the Unicode version by specifying `LPCWSTR` in your prototype and the function name `"GetFileAttributesExW"`. The latter is highly recommended.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks! I just copy 'n' pasted this together and obviously missed that. I've changed it in the post.

Answer (score 2):

The size and creation data (and more) are available via [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx).